# Android json processing

Tags: android, json

I'm reading json and it works fine.
But it's failed to add resulting String into the ArrayList.
Any ideas why ?

Here is the code.

StuffPics class (updated):

```
    public class StuffPics {
    private String imageUrl;
    public StuffPics() {
    }
    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }
    public String setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
          return this.imageUrl;
        }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StuffPics = " + this.imageUrl;
    }
```

}

Activity (updated):

```
    private ArrayList<StuffPics> mylist;
```

...

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{

            String url="http://www.test.com";
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
            int lengthJsonArr = jsonarray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
            {
                //build url
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                String autcElement = jsonChildNode.optString("picUrl").toString();
                String img= url + autcElement;
                System.out.println("imageUrl"+img); 
                //create object and add it to the list
                StuffPics pic = new StuffPics();
                pic.getImageUrl();
                System.out.print("PIC"+pic);
                mylist.add(pic);
            }
        }                   
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So, the first System.out shows strings, as they should be. Means json was read the right way.
But the second System.out shows nothing. Means I can't add strings into StuffPics pic. As the result ArrayList mylist is empty as well.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the exact output?

Comment: "But the second System.out shows nothing"

Comment: How can it show nothing? You're printing `"PIC"+pic`. That's not nothing...

Comment: Easy. When there is NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Well pic is a custom object `StuffPics` .

You will need to override `toString()` in order to see something

for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StuffPics = " + this.imageUrl;
}
```

also make sure mylist is initialized and you can adjust your code like this:

```
try{
    String url="http://www.test.com";
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
    int lengthJsonArr = jsonarray.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) 
    {
        //build url
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String autcElement = jsonChildNode.optString("picUrl").toString();
        String img= url + autcElement;
        System.out.println("imageUrl"+img); 
        //create object and add it to the list
        StuffPics pic = new StuffPics();
        pic.setImageUrl(img);
        System.out.print("PIC"+pic.toString());
        mylist.add(pic);
    }
}                   
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @JohnK `toString()` ? that goes in your `StuffPics` class bro

Comment: Do you mean just add into class or replace smth ?? Still the same when I added.

Comment: Yes because pic is not a string so use pic.toString() or pic.getImageUrl();

Comment: Yup, I see that pic is not a string, but when I use pic.getImageUrl(img); then I get "The method getImageUrl() in the type StuffPics is not applicable for the arguments(String). And @Override you provided above was added into the class StuffPics.

Comment: @JohnK use `pic.getImageUrl();` not `pic.getImageUrl(img);` because it is a getter, only setter takes a parameter

Comment: Nothing helps. Still NullPointerException. Do you want me to update code in the question according to the latest version ?

Comment: yes also which line is throwing the nulll pointer, did you initialize mylist like I suggested `mylist = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Updated. So now System.out.print("PIC"+pic); is throwing StuffPics=null and mylist.add(pic); is throwing NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) 
to view your custom objects.son is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation.

simply convert your object to a json using:

```
String json = new Gson().Json(pic);
```

and print it using logs.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
System.out.print("PIC"+pic);
```

with that:

```
System.out.print("PIC"+pic.getImageUrl());
```

Your list is not empty, you are only not able to see the URL you added.

Comment: There is NullPointerException. So, System.out will show nothing any way.

Comment: Can you post the full log? It's hard to know what is happening without details.